# Developing a VoIP/Chat Server-Client platform, where to start

Tags: xmpp, chat, messaging, voip, instant

I am interested in developing a Client and a Server for VoIP and IM communication like mumble/teamspeak/skype/raidcall etc.

I would like to stay away from hardcore stuff, while my main goals regarding the client are:

- Basic VoIP and Chat functionality
- Custom emoticons in chat
- A completely flat designed UI
- Project lasts one month

So is this in your opinion a realistic and doable concept? If so which language do you think that would fit my above goals the most? And can you also point me to a certain direction? (Like should I use xmpp, should I find a completed Server and develop only the client etc).

I can code in C, C++ and Java at a university level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I didn't start coding anything, I am still just looking around. I am trying to understand how to implement a custom UI, and how to code the chat/voip stuff. I am just surfing around.Most helpful thing I found is this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWYn1omeqqs but need more info. Also thanks for the welcome, didn't know it's not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at: www.freeradionetwork.eu

It's a prehistoric, but nevertheless interesting project. They published their protocol in hope for someone to write an API.

Do you want to stream through your server, or make it P2P?